# Resize Ubuntu side of dual boot UEFI

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I have a correctly running setup with dual-booted Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04. However, I would like to increase the root "partition" on the Ubuntu side, which has been complaining of low disk space. I have more than enough free unused space, but the Microsoft Reserved (MSR) partition on the Windows side kicks in once I boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Please list your partition setup

Comment: I've answered the question. My case was a very specific setup on a samsung laptop.

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I realized that the source of my confusion is the fact that Ubuntu was installed with WUBI. Also, the multi-boot via UEFI did something weird where it seems only one partition was used. Somehow, Ubuntu and windows boots from a single partition under a single SSD marked as an MBR.

Furthermore, I did not have enough space to do a clone of the root disk before a resize - I needed to resize in place.

These were the instructions I followed, which allowed me to do everything within 5 mintues on my SSD: [Ubuntu Help Wiki - resize wubi disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk)

1. You have to boot from a live CD/USB. This won't work while running Wubi.
2. Backup the root.disk (not required, but a good idea)
3. Mount the NTFS partition that your root.disk is on (this example assumes it's /dev/sda1 and the mountpoint is /media/win - adjust accordingly in the following instructions):

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /media/win
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/win
   ```
4. Check the size of the root.disk (not required)

   ```
   du -h --apparent-size /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
   ```
5. Run fsck on the root.disk

   ```
   fsck -f /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
   ```
6. Resize - specify the desired final size (this example resizes to 10 GB)

   ```
   resize2fs /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 10G
   ```
7. Reboot back into Wubi Ubuntu

I hope this helps others in my same, somewhat unusual situation, in the future. Please feel free to explain why the setup may have been done using a single partition as I set this up a long time ago, and simply chose the path of least resistance to get my laptop up and running. Everything was configured on a new SSD where I had to boot from USB to install.